# How I reduce time of launching my VSTO addins in Outlook Word and Excel

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, word-addins

When I am launching The addins like Outlook or Excel Addins , Its taking more than 10 secs,
and any form under that addins taking 5-6 min .
y client want fast launching of any Outlook , Excel or word and form will open in 2-3 sec.

How it can be Implement.

Comment: Please anyone can help ??

Comment: Have you tried to implement any logging in your addin to see which parts of your code take that long?